# Simplifying elements of a matrix

Tags: matrix, simplifying-expressions

These elements of the matrices can be simplified by hand much further{roots can be cancelled and all}, yet the Fullsimplify in Mathematica doesn't simply it completely.

[image]

The matrix is:

```
{{-((p^2 + Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] p3 - p0 (Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] + p3))/
   m), -(((p^2 + (m + Sqrt[m^2 + p^2]) (m - p0)) (-I p2 + Sqrt[
      p^2 - p2^2 - p3^2]))/(m (m + Sqrt[m^2 + p^2]))), (1/(
  m (m + Sqrt[m^2 + p^2])))(-p^2 p2 + Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] p0 p2 + 
    m (-Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] + p0) p2 - I p0 p3 Sqrt[p^2 - p2^2 - p3^2] + 
    I p3 Sqrt[-(m^2 + p^2) (-p^2 + p2^2 + p3^2)] + 
    I m^2 (I p2 + Sqrt[p^2 - p2^2 - p3^2]) + 
    I m (p3 Sqrt[p^2 - p2^2 - p3^2] + 
       Sqrt[-(m^2 + p^2) (-p^2 + p2^2 + p3^2)])), (1/(
  m (m + Sqrt[m^2 + p^2])))(-I (Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] - p0) p2^2 + 
    I m^2 (p0 - p3) - 
    I p3 (p^2 + Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] p3 - p0 (Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] + p3)) + 
    p2 (-p0 Sqrt[p^2 - p2^2 - p3^2] + 
       Sqrt[-(m^2 + p^2) (-p^2 + p2^2 + p3^2)]) + 
    m (I (p0 - p3) (Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] + p3) + 
       p2 (-I p2 + Sqrt[p^2 - p2^2 - p3^2])))}, {-(((p^2 + (m + Sqrt[
         m^2 + p^2]) (m - p0)) (I p2 + Sqrt[p^2 - p2^2 - p3^2]))/(
   m (m + Sqrt[m^2 + p^2]))), (-p^2 + p0 (Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] - p3) + 
   Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] p3)/m, (1/(
  m (m + Sqrt[m^2 + p^2])))(-I (Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] - p0) p2^2 + 
    I m^2 (p0 + p3) + I m (Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] - p3) (p0 + p3) + 
    I p3 (p^2 - Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] p0 - Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] p3 + p0 p3) + 
    p0 p2 Sqrt[p^2 - p2^2 - p3^2] - 
    p2 Sqrt[-(m^2 + p^2) (-p^2 + p2^2 + p3^2)] - 
    m p2 (I p2 + Sqrt[p^2 - p2^2 - p3^2])), (1/(
  m (m + Sqrt[m^2 + p^2])))(p^2 p2 + m (Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] - p0) p2 - 
    Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] p0 p2 + I p0 p3 Sqrt[p^2 - p2^2 - p3^2] - 
    I p3 Sqrt[-(m^2 + p^2) (-p^2 + p2^2 + p3^2)] + 
    m^2 (p2 + I Sqrt[p^2 - p2^2 - p3^2]) + 
    I m (-p3 Sqrt[p^2 - p2^2 - p3^2] + 
       Sqrt[-(m^2 + p^2) (-p^2 + p2^2 + p3^2)]))}, {(1/(
  m (m + Sqrt[m^2 + p^2])))(-p^2 p2 + Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] p0 p2 + 
    m (-Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] + p0) p2 + I p0 p3 Sqrt[p^2 - p2^2 - p3^2] - 
    I p3 Sqrt[-(m^2 + p^2) (-p^2 + p2^2 + p3^2)] + 
    I m^2 (I p2 + Sqrt[p^2 - p2^2 - p3^2]) + 
    I m (-p3 Sqrt[p^2 - p2^2 - p3^2] + 
       Sqrt[-(m^2 + p^2) (-p^2 + p2^2 + p3^2)])), (1/(
  m (m + Sqrt[m^2 + p^2])))(I (Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] - p0) p2^2 - 
    I m^2 (p0 + p3) + 
    I p3 (-p^2 + Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] p0 + Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] p3 - p0 p3) + 
    p0 p2 Sqrt[p^2 - p2^2 - p3^2] - 
    p2 Sqrt[-(m^2 + p^2) (-p^2 + p2^2 + p3^2)] - 
    I m ((Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] - p3) (p0 + p3) + 
       p2 (-p2 - I Sqrt[p^2 - p2^2 - p3^2]))), (-p^2 + 
   p0 (Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] - p3) + Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] p3)/
  m, ((p^2 + (m + Sqrt[m^2 + p^2]) (m - p0)) (-I p2 + Sqrt[
     p^2 - p2^2 - p3^2]))/(m (m + Sqrt[m^2 + p^2]))}, {(1/(
  m (m + Sqrt[m^2 + p^2])))(I (Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] - p0) p2^2 - 
    I m^2 (p0 - p3) + 
    I p3 (p^2 + Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] p3 - p0 (Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] + p3)) + 
    p2 (-p0 Sqrt[p^2 - p2^2 - p3^2] + 
       Sqrt[-(m^2 + p^2) (-p^2 + p2^2 + p3^2)]) + 
    m (-I (p0 - p3) (Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] + p3) + 
       p2 (I p2 + Sqrt[p^2 - p2^2 - p3^2]))), (1/(
  m (m + Sqrt[m^2 + p^2])))(p^2 p2 + m (Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] - p0) p2 - 
    Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] p0 p2 - I p0 p3 Sqrt[p^2 - p2^2 - p3^2] + 
    I p3 Sqrt[-(m^2 + p^2) (-p^2 + p2^2 + p3^2)] + 
    m^2 (p2 + I Sqrt[p^2 - p2^2 - p3^2]) + 
    I m (p3 Sqrt[p^2 - p2^2 - p3^2] + 
       Sqrt[-(m^2 + p^2) (-p^2 + p2^2 + p3^2)])), ((p^2 + (m + Sqrt[
        m^2 + p^2]) (m - p0)) (I p2 + Sqrt[p^2 - p2^2 - p3^2]))/(
  m (m + Sqrt[m^2 + p^2])), -((
   p^2 + Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] p3 - p0 (Sqrt[m^2 + p^2] + p3))/m)}}
```

some of the substitution we can make are (already taken),

```
{p1 -> Sqrt[p^2 - p2^2 - p3^2], e -> Sqrt[p^2 + m^2]}
Assuming[{Element[{p0, p, p2, p3}, Reals], m > 0}, sat2 = sat // FullSimplify]
```

What more could be done to simplify the elements of the matrix?

Comment: Choose ONE representative element of this matrix, show the simplification you refer to, and include the final simplified version you would like to obtain. If you focus the question better, you are more likely to obtain effective answers.

Comment: Ok I will do that, but that is a more lengthy process